# how to pull the parameter from cdata response and use it in another request using groovy in soapUi

Tags: groovy, soapui, cdata

1. This is my response from soapUI

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
          <SearchAirFaresResponse xmlns="http://www.sample.com/xchange">
           <SearchAirFaresResult>
            <![CDATA[
             <FareSearchResponse>
               <MasterDetails>
                  <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
                  <RecStNo>1</RecStNo>
                  <SessionID>5705b1a6-95ac-486c-88a1f90f85e57590</SessionID>
                </MasterDetails>
                </FareSearchResponse>
            ]]>
        </SearchAirFaresResult>
     </SearchAirFaresResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

2. How to extract SessionID element which is inside CDATA using groovy script and use it in another request like

   ```
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <xch:GetMoreFares>
       <xch:sGetMoreFare>
      <![CDATA[
       <MoreFlights>
       <MasterDetails>
           <NoOfResult Index="1">40</NoOfResult>
           <BranchId>1</BranchId>
           <SessionId>5705b1a6-95ac-486c-88a1f90f85e57590</SessionId>
       </MasterDetails>
       <Journey>DOM</Journey>
       <ResponseType>XML</ResponseType>
       <SearchType>OW</SearchType>
       </MoreFlights>
       ]]>
       </xch:sGetMoreFare>
     </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
   ```

   3.I have been searching lot but didnt get the right one,and also am new to groovy script using soapUi , pls guide me stepwise procedure in soapUi to implement .

Comment: Looks like you got different type of responses and you want to extract `sid` from both responses? By the way, 1st response does not seem to be well-formed and is `searchResponse` really nested . Can you provide right xml? update the question.

Comment: Actually i need to send the request like 2nd xml structure which i have mentioned in no 2

Comment: Have you tried anything from the official documentation? https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also most similar to albciff's answer, but with little variant (using reusable closure to parse).

Here is the `Script Assertion` for the first request step. This will avoid additional groovy script step in the test case.

Please follow the appropriate comments inline:

**Script Assertion:**

```groovy
/**
 * This is Script Assertion for the first
 * request step which extracts cdata from response,
 * then sessionId from extracted cdata. And
 * Assigns the value at test case level, so that
 * it can be used in the rest of the test steps of
 * the same test case.
 * However, it is possible to store the sessionId
 * at Suite level as well if you want use the sessionId
 * across the test cases too. 
 * 
 * */

/**
* Closure to search for certain element data
* input parameters
* xml data, element name to search
**/
def searchData = { data, element ->
   def parsedData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
   parsedData?.'**'.find { it.name() == element} as String
}

//Assert the response
assert context.response, "Current step response is empty or null"

//Get the cdata part which is inside element "SearchAirFaresResult"
def cData = searchData(context.response,'SearchAirFaresResult')
//Assert CDATA part is not null
assert cData, "Extracted CDATA of the response is empty or null"

//Get the SessionID from cdata
def sessionId = searchData(cData, 'SessionID')
//Assert sessionId is not null or empty
assert sessionId, "Session Id is empty or null"
log.info "Session id of response  $sessionId1" 

//Set the session to test case level custom property
//So, that it can be used for the rest of the steps 
//in the same test case
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('SESSION_ID', sessionId)
```

In the following test steps, you can use the saved `SESSION_ID` in the following ways:

- If the following step is request step (REST, SOAP, HTTP, JDBC etc), then use [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) `${#TestCase#SESSION_ID}` like `<SessionId>${#TestCase#SESSION_ID}</SessionId>`
- If the following step is groovy script, then use one of the below:
  `context.expand('${#TestCase#SESSION_ID}')` or
  `context.testCase.getPropertyValue('SESSION_ID')` or
  `testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue('SESSION_ID')`

Comment: Hi how do i select the attribute name "Index" from the above mentioned example, I tried by giving the xpath but ended in getting error.

Comment: @vikkiwiggi, there is no `Index` in the first response, right? And the above script is to get data from response. If you have a different question, would you mind opening a new question?

Comment: suppose <NoOfResult Index="1">40</NoOfResult> is in the response then how do I take that, I have used ur previous steps to get the index attribute ,but am able to get ly node values not attribute values

Answer (score 1):

To do so you can use a *Groovy* testStep, inside it get the SOAP testStep where you've the response with desired `sessionID` and use a [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) to parse the response and get the `CDATA` value. Note that `XmlSlurper` treat `CDATA` as `String` so you've to parse it again. Finally save the returned value as a `TestSuite` or `TestCase` level (in the example I use `TestCase`):

```
// get your first testStep by its name
def tr = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('Test Request')
// get your response
def response = tr.getPropertyValue('response')
// parse the response and find the node with CDATA content
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
def cdataContent = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'SearchAirFaresResponse' }
// XmlSlurper treat CDATA as String so you've to parse
// its content again
def cdata = new XmlSlurper().parseText(cdataContent.toString())
// finally get the SessionID node content
def sessionId = cdata.'**'.find { it.name() == 'SessionID' }

// now save this value at some level (for example testCase) in
// order to get it later
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('MySessionId',sessionId.toString())
```

Then change a bit your second testStep to use [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) to get the `MySessionId` property in your second request as `${#TestCase#MySessionId}`:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
   <xch:GetMoreFares>
    <xch:sGetMoreFare>
   <![CDATA[
    <MoreFlights>
    <MasterDetails>
        <NoOfResult Index="1">40</NoOfResult>
        <BranchId>1</BranchId>
        <SessionId>${#TestCase#MySessionId}</SessionId>
    </MasterDetails>
    <Journey>DOM</Journey>
    <ResponseType>XML</ResponseType>
    <SearchType>OW</SearchType>
    </MoreFlights>
    ]]>
    </xch:sGetMoreFare>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi how do i select the attribute name "Index" from the above mentioned example, I tried by giving the xpath but ended in getting error.